# How to define materials in Asymptote?

Tags: graphics, 3d, asymptote, rendering

I searched in the Asymptote documentation and found that material is handled as a structure in three_light.asy that has the following definition:

```
struct material {
pen[] p; // diffusepen,ambientpen,emissivepen,specularpen
real opacity;
real shininess;
void operator init(pen diffusepen=black, pen ambientpen=black,
                 pen emissivepen=black, pen specularpen=mediumgray,
                 real opacity=opacity(diffusepen),
                 real shininess=defaultshininess) {
p=new pen[] {diffusepen,ambientpen,emissivepen,specularpen};
this.opacity=opacity;
this.shininess=shininess;
}
```

The document says these are used to

> implement OpenGL-style lighting, based on the Phong-Blinn specular
>   model.

Where do I get information/examples of how to define the parameters?  For example, how do I take advantage of this to define a glass material and draw a glass cup/cube that has a certain amount of deflection/transparency?  Or are there available material definitions that I can start with?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/243483/484 has a lot of the info you are looking for. You can play around with opacity (which was not discussed there), but fair warning: transparent surfaces tend to look pretty bad in Asymptote. And I doubt the phong-blinn specular model could ever produce good looking glass -- that probably requires ray tracing.